# Contact form doesn't transfer data from AngularJS to PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve data from AngularJS file to PHP file, but I get the error that it's empty.
I can't find any good examples that are dealing with posting data from angularJS to php file and so I need help.

**Angularjs file:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ajoslin.promise-tracker'])
.controller('help', function ($scope, $http, $log, promiseTracker, $timeout) {

$scope.ph_numbr =/[0-9]+/;


// Form submit handler.
$scope.submit = function(form) {
  // Trigger validation flag.
  $scope.submitted = true;

  // If form is invalid, return and let AngularJS show validation errors.
  if (!$scope.toggle || $scope.toggle.length <= 0 || form.$invalid) {
    return;
  }

  // Default values for the request.
  $scope.progress = promiseTracker('progress');
  var config = {
    params : {
      //'callback' : 'JSON_CALLBACK',
      'name' : $scope.name,
      'email' : $scope.email,
      'toggle' : $scope.toggle,
      'phone' : $scope.phone,
      'comments' : $scope.comments
    },
    tracker : 'progress'
  };


  $http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : 'js/contact.php',
                    data: config,
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}  

            })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      if (data.success) {
        $scope.name = null;
        $scope.email = null;
        $scope.toggle = null;
        $scope.phone = null;
        $scope.comments = null;
        $scope.messages = 'Your form has been sent!';
        $scope.submitted = false;
      } else {
        $scope.messages = 'Oops, we received your request, but there was an error processing it.';
        $log.error(data);
      }
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.progress = data;
      $scope.messages = 'There was a network error. Try again later.';
      $log.error(data);
    });

  // Hide the status message which was set above after 3 seconds.
  var promise = $timeout(function() { 
    $scope.messages = null; 
    }, 3000); 
    $scope.progress.addPromise(promise);
  };
});
```

**php file:**

```
<?php
/*error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once 'js/PHPMailerAutoload.php';*/

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$postData = json_decode($data);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['toggle']) && isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['toggle']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);

    $subject = trim($_POST['toggle']);
    //email address settings
    $my_address = "*@yahoo.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$email;
    $message = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . $_POST["phone"] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['comments']);
    $to = $my_address;

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
    echo json_encode($data);


} else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);

}

?>
```

The error message that I get is: "Please fill out the form completely" - which means it doesn't get the values.

My other question is how in the AngularJS do I retrieve the data.success value from the php file?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting the data here:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$postData = json_decode($data);
```

but then you're using `$_POST` instead. Perhaps this would work:

```
if (empty($postData['name']) //etc
```

It looks like you're accessing `data.success` appropriately and the value should be set to `false` as your code currently is.

#### Additional code review:

If there are errors on the server, it's best to return a status code that indicates that. As is, the server is returning `200` (default), which means everything is OK, even though the request is actually failing. That would eliminate the need for `data.success`. If the  server sends status `200`, your `.success` function will fire. If it returns an error status, like `404`, then your `.error` function would fire instead.

I have doubts about your need of the `Content-Type` header. You might want to reconsider if that's necessary.

On your Angular form, you ought to nest those `$scope` properties in an object:

```
$scope.formData = {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  //etc
}
```

Then, you can simply pass that directly to your `$http` call and to reset the values you can simply do `$scope.formData = {}`.

Comment: Don't I already nest the $scope properties here:
      var config = {
    params : {
      //'callback' : 'JSON_CALLBACK',
      'name' : $scope.name,
      'email' : $scope.email,
      'toggle' : $scope.toggle,
      'phone' : $scope.phone,
      'comments' : $scope.comments
    },
    tracker : 'progress'
  };

Comment: @keren7 You're not understanding the point... you're manually nesting them later. Start that way. `$scope.formData.name` in the controller and `ng-model="formData.name"` in the view.

Comment: @keren7 I haven't heard anything back from you and you haven't marked my answer accepted. Is there anything still unclear?

Comment: Thank you for checking up on me. I still haven't figured out what's the problem. I've changed my code and it still not working. It seems like the php file is not getting the data even though the app.js is transferring the data. Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CWAZuo9VsjChz3e7uqWz?p=preview

Comment: @keren7 I still suggest following all of the suggestions I made, but it does appear that you're getting the data to the `http` call.  The next thing I wonder is if you're definitely making a request to the file that you think you are. You have a relative path as the url, so it may not be finding the file you think it is. Whether there's a problem there depends on how your server is setup and what url you're running that code from. It would be better to have a relative path from the root by starting the url with a `/` like `/path/to/file.php` rather than `path/to/file/php`.

Comment: @keren7 you can check your network tab in the browser dev tools to see exactly what's happening with that request.